# Deducing template arguments

Tags: c++

I wrote code to construct binary search tree and also a bfs a binary search tree to test whether it works, but i got a lot of bugs, I debug them  for a long time and cannot find the bug.

```
#include<vector>

template<typename Key, typename Value>
struct BSTNode{
    Key key;
    Value value;
    BSTNode * left;
    BSTNode * right;
    BSTNode(Key k, Value v, BSTNode *l=NULL, BSTNode *r=NULL) :
    key(k), value(v), left(l), right(r) {}
};

template<typename Key, typename Value>
BSTNode<Key, Value>* min_height(std::vector<int> &v, int left, int right ) {
    if(left<=right){
        int mid=left+ (right-left)/2;
        BSTNode<Key, Value>* node=new BSTNode<Key, Value>(v[mid], v[mid]);
        node->left=min_height(v, left, mid-1 );
        node->right=min_height(v, mid+1, right );
        return node;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    BSTNode<int, int>* root=min_height(v, 0, 5);
}
```

Compiler error:

> ```
> prog.cpp: In function ‘BSTNode<Key, Value>* min_height(std::vector<int>&, int, int)’:
> prog.cpp:48:42: error: no matching function for call to ‘min_height(std::vector<int>&, int&, int&)’
> prog.cpp:48:42: note: candidate is:
> prog.cpp:44:22: note: template<class Key, class Value> BSTNode<Key, Value>* min_height(std::vector<int>&, int, int)
> prog.cpp:44:22: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> prog.cpp:48:42: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Key’
> prog.cpp:49:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘min_height(std::vector<int>&, int&, int&)’
> prog.cpp:49:41: note: candidate is:
> prog.cpp:44:22: note: template<class Key, class Value> BSTNode<Key, Value>* min_height(std::vector<int>&, int, int)
> prog.cpp:44:22: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> prog.cpp:49:41: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Key’
> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> prog.cpp:63:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘min_height(std::vector<int>&, int, int)’
> prog.cpp:63:45: note: candidate is:
> prog.cpp:44:22: note: template<class Key, class Value> BSTNode<Key, Value>* min_height(std::vector<int>&, int, int)
> prog.cpp:44:22: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> prog.cpp:63:45: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Key’
> prog.cpp:63:22: warning: unused variable ‘root’ [-Wunused-variable]
> ```

Comment: Are you serious???  We are not human compilers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't deduce template types based upon the return type.

You can be explicit though:

```
BSTNode<int, int>* root = min_height<int, int>(v, 0, 5);
```

For this to work though, you also need to update your function to be explicit in its calls to `min_height`:

```
node->left = min_height<Key, Value>(v, left, mid - 1);
node->right = min_height<Key, Value>(v, mid + 1, right);
```

However, by the looks of it, `min_height` is always putting integers into `Key` and `Value`. You could make it more generic by taking a `vector` of some `Type`, and more explicit by using that type as the `Key` and `Value` types.

```
template<typename Type>
BSTNode<Type, Type>* min_height(vector<Type> &v, int left, int right ) {
    if(left<=right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left)/2;
        BSTNode<Type, Type>* node = new BSTNode<Type, Type>(v[mid], v[mid]);
        node->left = min_height(v, left, mid - 1);
        node->right = min_height(v, mid+1, right);
        return node;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
BSTNode<int, int>* root = min_height(v, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Peter! I try the second solution and it works.

Comment: But for the first solution, complier still gave me wrong message:

Comment: which is the same problem.

Comment: I would like to know what do you mean by "You can't deduce template types based upon the return type."?

Comment: I've updated the answer. The internal calls to `min_height` also needed their types to be made explicit.

Comment: A templated function decides what the actual template types are at the place it is called. It uses the types of parameters passed in to determine what to use in the function. You can also be explicit, e.g. `func<int>();`. The only thing you can't use to determine the template types is the return type. The compiler won't tell the difference between `double ret = func();` and `int ret = func();`.

Comment: And I would like to know why when only one argument in template my previous writing works, but two arguments in template cannot work?

Comment: If you have an example, formulate it as a new question.