# Deducing template arguments continue

Tags: c++

In this case which is a binary tree not a binary search tree, there is only one argument in template which is type T. As showed in the main function, I don't need explicit min_height(v, 0, 5), but min_height(v, 0, 5) is enough. However, in the binary search tree case, there are two template arguments, the usage doesn't work. I would like to know why?  Thank you very much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
struct BTNode{
 T data;
 BTNode * left;
 BTNode * right;
 BTNode(T d, BTNode *left=NULL, BTNode * right=NULL): data(d) {} 
 };

template<typename T>
BTNode<T>* min_height(vector<T> &v, int left, int right ){// here is different from my paper code

 if(left<=right){
    int mid=left+ (right-left)/2;
    BTNode<T>* node=new BTNode<T>(v[mid]);
    node->left=min_height(v, left, mid-1 );
    node->right=min_height(v, mid+1, right );
    return node;
    }
}

int main() {
  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);
  v.push_back(4);
  v.push_back(5);
  v.push_back(6);
  BTNode<int>* root=min_height(v, 0, 5);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: All I get on GCC 4.7.2 after fixing unused variables is that not all paths of `min_height` return a value.

Comment: Please refer to my previous question's link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349589/deducing-template-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the case of the single template parameter T, you are using T in one of the arguments, the first one, the vector &v. So when the compiler sees the line

```
BTNode<int>* root=min_height(v, 0, 5);
```

in main() it tries to deduce the type of T, sees that the first argument v is of type `vector<int>` and can deduce that T = int.

In the other case in your previous question, the second template parameter Value was not in any of the types passed to the min_height function. It was only in the returned type, but C++ cannot deduce the template parameter type from the type of the return value, only from the type of the passed-in arguments, so it could not determine what type to use for Value and you had to explicitly specify it using `min_height<int,int>`.